# MergeSort - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, sorting, merge, indexoutofboundsexception, mergesort

I am sorry if this has already been answered somewhere, I have spent over an hour searching through many previous questions and none of them were able to help me with this error.

I randomly receive an error, probably 70% of the time:

```
--------------------Configuration: MergeSort - JDK version 1.7.0_45 <Default> - <Default>-    -------------------

Random array: 17 14 3 4 1 10 13 9 3 1 6 9 10 2 17 8 10 5 7 8 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20

at MergeSort.merge(MergeSort.java:64)
at MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:26)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:18)

Process completed.
```

Line 64 would refer to: "scratch[scratch_index] = list[i];"

```
public void merge(int[] list, int first, int middle, int last)
{
    int[] scratch = new int[list.length];

    int midpoint = (first+last)/2;

    int left_index = first;
    int right_index = middle + 1;
    int scratch_index = left_index;

    while((left_index <= midpoint) && (right_index <= last))
    {
        if(list[left_index] <= list[right_index])
        {
            scratch[scratch_index] = list[left_index];
            left_index +=1;
        }
        else
        {
            scratch[scratch_index] = list[right_index];
            right_index +=1;
        }
        scratch_index +=1;
    }

    for(int i=left_index;i<=midpoint;i++)
    {
        scratch[scratch_index] = list[i];
        scratch_index +=1;
    }
    for(int i=right_index;right_index<=last;i++) // I am line 64
    {
        scratch[scratch_index] = list[i];
        scratch_index +=1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {
        list[i] = scratch[i];
    }
}
```

This is my first question ever on this site, sorry if I have not formatted this question correctly, any advice is appreciated.

If any other information is needed to help me with solving this error, just let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: where this method has been called ?

Comment: Did you try what I posted ?

Comment: mergeSort:
    public void mergeSort(int[] list, int first, int last)
  {
   if(first<last)
   {
    int middle = (first+last)/2;
    sort(list, first, middle);
    sort(list, middle+1, last);
    merge(list,first, middle, last);
   }
  }

Comment: All working now, thank you everyone! It was what Amir said, I had overlooked the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the comment `// I am line 64` You are incrementing the `i` and not the `right_index` which will cause the index to keep increasing until reaching index out of bound, so replace this,

```
for(int i=right_index;right_index<=last;i++) // I am line 64
```

by this:

```
for(int i=right_index; i<=last;i++)
```

Comment: This fixed everything, sometimes we miss the simplest of things.
Thank you to everyone who helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Indexes use "zero-based numbering" >> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

```
String example = "01234";
System.out.println(example.size()); //Prints out 5
System.out.println(exmaple.indexOf("1")); //Prints out 1
```

Your for statement needs to be checking up TO the last index

```
for(int i=right_index;right_index<last;i++)
```

OR (not recommended)

```
for(int i=right_index;right_index<=last-1;i++) //Works, but not recommended due to conventions
```

```
//index       0  1  2 3 4 5  6  7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Random array: 17 14 3 4 1 10 13 9 3 1 6  9  10 2  17 8  10 5  7  8 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
```

Comment: Thank you, now for some reason I always get a "0" added to the end of the Sorted Array. I changed two of the for loops to < instead of <=

Still though I am randomly getting the same error. So not fixed yet :(